# Programmatically generate android layouts

Tags: android

I want to generate programmatically one layout and in layout one textview and edittext. How can I make it look like this?

[image]

There is code but it didnt work :(

```
RelativeLayout mRlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mRlayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mRparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
EditText myEditText = new EditText(context);
myEditText.setLayoutParams(mRparams);
mRlayout.addView(myEditText);
```

Comment: for what you want to create new layout??

Comment: We won't do your homework.

Comment: You want to do it? Then feel free to do it...

Comment: Nobody here is going to do your work for you.

Comment: Did you tried ? even search ??

Comment: I can never find a good close reason for such questions...

Comment: This seems like a very basic question and it sounds like you're trying to avoid doing your own work. Please don't post questions like that; as you might guess from the comments above, they are not welcome. Please review the help files laying out what constitutes a good question.

Comment: problem is the setContentView dident work in my class ..this is only class not activity or dialog.. it will bi part for some element but i want use it for generate n elements

Answer (score 1):

first add linear layout in xml file like

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizantalLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horiontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

and then create object of linear layout in your java code

```
    EditText myEditText = new EditText(this); // Pass it an Activity or Context
    LayoutParams editLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);            
    myEditText.setLayoutParams(editLayoutParams);

    myEditText.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    myEditText.setHint(hint);
    myEditText.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    myLayout.addView(myEditText);// myLayout is object of linear layout created in xml file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("TextView");
        layout.addView(textView);
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
        editText.setHint("EditText");
        layout.addView(editText);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is the setContentView dident work in my class ..this is only class not activity or dialog.. it will bi part for some element but i want use it for generate n elements

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest define LinearLayout inside layout.xml and Create object in Java and then add textview the LinearLayout.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relatedChannels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout cat_linear=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_Category);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("This is Text View");
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    cat_linear.addView(tv);


    EditText ed = new EditText (context);
    ed.setHint("EditText");
    ed.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    cat_linear.addView(ed);
}
```